# On what systems sleep() is not a pthread cancellation point?

Tags: c, pthreads

pthread_cancel() successfully interrupts sleep() on Solaris 10, Linux and Cygwin.
So why people use pthread_cond_timedwait() instead of sleep()?
In the following example PPBsleep() is the function I found in some library. I think it's vulnerable to system clock adjustments.

PPBsleep2() I wrote myself. I think it's no worse than PPBsleep(). And the plain sleep() works too.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int PPBsleep(int seconds)
{
  int  rc;
  struct timeval now;
  struct timespec timeout;
  pthread_cond_t sleep_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
  pthread_mutex_t sleep_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

  rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&sleep_mutex);

  rc = gettimeofday(&now,NULL);

  timeout.tv_sec = now.tv_sec + (long)seconds;
  timeout.tv_nsec = now.tv_usec * 1000L;
  rc = 0;
  while(rc != ETIMEDOUT) {
    rc = pthread_cond_timedwait(&sleep_cond, &sleep_mutex, &timeout);
  }

  rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&sleep_mutex);

  return 0;
}

int PPBsleep2(int seconds)
{
  int oldtype;
  pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, &oldtype);
  sleep(seconds);
  pthread_setcanceltype(oldtype, NULL);
  return 0;
}

void *ThreadStartFunction(void *inp)
{
  pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, NULL);
  //pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
  printf("before sleep\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  //PPBsleep2(4);
  sleep(4);
  printf("after sleep\n");
  fflush(stdout);
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  int rc;
  void *res;
  pthread_t thread;
  rc = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, ThreadStartFunction, NULL);
  sleep(1);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, &res);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: so does `wait()` but there are slight differences which are going to be explained by pros

Comment: `sleep()` is required to be a cancellation point, there are other reasons not to use it though (eg. possible use of `SIGALARM`). Also, I don't think I've ever seen anyone use `pthread_cond_timedwait()` as a delay function, more often `select()` or `nanosleep()`

Comment: because they learned it / where taught so

Comment: Also, as an aside. It's customary not to directly set the time, but rather change its speed until it reaches a certain time. This helps you avoid something like cron missing a scheduled job, and other highly confused software.

Answer (score 2):

`sleep()` is required the be a cancellation point by POSIX (see [this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html#tag_02_09_05_02) for a list of cancellation points.)

Therefore, it should act as a cancellation point on any POSIX compliant system.